# Certificates in smartphones' application

Tags: android, iphone, security, windows-phone, key-pair

Currently, I'm developing a mobile app which communicate directly with my server.

First of all, my app must operate on iOS, Android, Windows Phone and BlackBarry OS, but this is not the subject of this topic.

The problem is that before communicate with my server, this app need to authenticate its self to my server with a key pair (public/private).

How should it work? I read somewhere that each app has its own "ressources" folder, maybe a .P12 file could be save there? Would it work on each mobile OS? What are security constraints?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use certificates in your apps. I use the same client certificate for Android and iOS.

For **iOS**, you need to import your .p12 file. [Check here](http://intrepidusgroup.com/insight/2011/10/mutual-authentication-in-android-and-ios/)

For **Android**, I used a library named BouncyCastle, so you can import .bks (keystores) and use them. Check [this site](http://blog.callistaenterprise.se/2011/11/24/android-tlsssl-mutual-authentication/).

Comment: Alright, thank you for your answer. But, for example on iOS, where is this .p12 file saved?

Comment: You can add your .p12 file with the other resources, directly in your application, and access it with `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@“clientCert" ofType:@"p12"]`

Comment: Ok, thanks again. Do you know if it's possible to save p12 files (or any files) as ressource for Windows Phone and BB app?

Comment: And my another question: is it safe to store p12 file which allows to communicate to the server directly as a ressource? Could an attacker just access to "ressource" folder and get p12 file?

Comment: @Eleon I have no idea about WP and BB, but they probably also implement this feature. Your .p12 file is protected with a password. I don't know a lot about security, but everything you'll code will be shipped in your app (the certificate too), so it might be possible to retrieve it. Consider your app public.